# Parallel IPython detects closures in list comprehension

Tags: python, ipython, pickle, ipython-parallel

I want to parallelize some python code with `IPython.parallel` and have the problem, that IPython detects closures while executing a parallel function.

My environment get's initialized by:

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
c = Client()
v = c.direct_view()

qs = [1,2,3,4]
```

The function is defined as:

```
@v.parallel(block=True)
def pbands(qs):
    i = 1 # This should normally be a loop variable inside the function
    valar = [i for j in range(3)]
    return 0
```

Executing this function as

```
pbands(qs)
```

yields the error

```
ValueError: Sorry, cannot pickle code objects with closures
```

Replacing the `i` inside the list comprehension with a literal number or `j`, doesn't create an error, but this is no suitable solution, because in the real code `i` will be a loop variable.

Is there a way, to get this list comprehension working?

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 creates closures on list comprehensions. This code wouldn't be a problem on Python 2.

IPython doesn't handle closures. This will be fixed (differently) in IPython 3.0 ([adding simple closure support](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/5761)) and 2.1 ([fixing the closure check](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/5762)). If you tell IPython to use `dill`, a lot more things will be serializable, including this particular bit of code:

```
rc[:].use_dill()
```

`DirectView.use_dill` is new in IPython 2.0.

Comment: I tried your solution with `dill 0.2b1`, but this leads to some different errors (`KeyErrors` and `UnpicklingError: pickle exhausted before end of frame`).

Comment: That's an older version of `dill`, maybe try again with version `dill-0.2`.